# Access a .Net attribute's properties from within it's target (e.g. method)

Tags: .net, aop

Is it possible to access an attribute's properties from within the item to which it's applied (e.g. a method)?  For example, with the code below, could I access a property on the "RequiresConnection" attribute from with the "Search" method?

```
    [RequiresConnection]
    public SearchResult Search(SearchInfo searchInfo)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure

```
class TheClass {
  [RequiresConnection]
  public SearchResult Search(SearchInfo searchInfo) {
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(TheClass).GetMethod("Search");
    RequiresConnection attrib = (RequiresConnection).methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
      typeof(RequiresConnection),
      false)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx). The example is not specifically doing what you want but you can adapt it by calling `GetCustomAttributes` from within your method.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. That will be something along

```
var attributes = StackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes();
```